# Internet Explorer doesn't display image. Image ‘src’ remains blank

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8, getelementbyid, src

I hope you're well.

### Short:

My HTML reads:

```
<img id="JavImage">
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"
            src="http://www.foobar.com/Contents.js"></script>
</img>
```

and my *Contents.js* reads:

```
document.getElementById("JavImage").src="https://www.foobar.com/imgURL.jpg";
```

It displays the image `imgURL` correctly in FF15, but doesn't display it at all in IE8. I checked the source and FF added the 'src' attribute appropriately, whereas the 'src' attribute had not been appended in IE8.

From my research on these forums, IE has issues with the `getElementById` and `getElementsByName`, however `<img id="JavImage" name="JavImage"></img>` also didn't work.

Please advise. For more information, see below.

---

### Long:

I have a simple HTML page reading:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.foobar.com/JavPage.js"></script>`
```

and *JavPage.js* reads:

```
 document.write('<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>...<body><a id="JavHeader"><script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.foobar.com/Contents.js"></script></a>...</html>');
```

and *Contents.js* reads:

```
document.getElementById("JavHeader").href="www.foobar.com";
document.getElementById("JavHeader").innerHTML="Foobar";
```

There are various such elements with corresponding IDs in Contents.js.

**My intention was to allow the HTML to be written by an external file, so that it can be edited remotely. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?**

The simple HTML page renders the entirety of the Javascript, but some elements work in Firefox/Chrome that don't work in IE (See **Short**). Please advise.

Comment: Don't put the script tags inside the `a` and `img` tags, and wait with executing the JS until the page has loaded (by using the `load` or document ready events).

Comment: The code presented in the “Short” version works on IE, when incorrect URLs are replaced by suitable correct URLs. The “Long” version seems to ask about something completely different, and the “intention” part has no obvious connection with anything else.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, Jukka. I tried "http://ycombinator.com/images/yc500.gif" as a sample image, and it loaded in FF, but it still didn't load in IE.
I'll ensure I don't cram too much into a post, next time.

Answer (score 0):

for

```
<img id="JavImage"><script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.foobar.com/Contents.js"></script></img>
```

image object might not be rendered by browser when your javascript is being called.
so you can make your function to be called after load of page